# NodeJS,MongoDB - Return a JSON response from aggregate inside a GET request

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregate, response, middleware

I created an aggregate pipeline that returns many documents from my database.I can also see the results using "console.log" .But i can't return the results in a response when i am using Postman.You can test it on PostMan using AreaName=Hungary,Resolution=PT15M,Year=2018,Month=1,Day=1

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var assert = require('assert')
const URL = 'mongodb+srv://user:user@cluster0-0pwss.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
//const CircularJSON = require('circular-json');
//const {parse, stringify} = require('flatted/cjs');



router.get('/:AreaName/:Resolution/:Year/:Month/:Day', (req, res, next) => {
  const _AreaName=req.params.AreaName
  const _Resolution=req.params.Resolution
  const _Year = parseInt(req.params.Year)
  const _Month = parseInt(req.params.Month)
  const _Day = parseInt(req.params.Day)

  MongoClient.connect(URL,{
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true}, 
    async (err, client) => {
      if (err) throw err; 
      else console.log('connected to db');
      assert.equal(null, err) 
      const db = client.db('energy')
      var collection = db.collection('ActualTotalLoad')
      const agg = [
        { 
          $match : 
          {
            AreaName: _AreaName,
            Day : _Day,
            Month: _Month,
            Year: _Year
          }
      },
        
        {
          $lookup:
          {
            from: 'ResolutionCode',
            localField: 'ResolutionCodeId',
            foreignField : 'Id',
            as: "resolution_codes"
          }
        },
        {
          $unwind: {path : "$resolution_codes"}
        },

        { 
          $match : {'resolution_codes.ResolutionCodeText' : _Resolution}
        },
        {
          $addFields : {ResolutionCode : '$resolution_codes.ResolutionCodeText',
                        Source :'entso-e',
                        Dataset :'ActualTotalLoad'
        }
        },

        {
          $project : 
          {
            _id:0,
            Id : 1,
            ResolutionCodeId:1,
            Source : 1,
            AreaName: 1,
            Year : 1,
            Month : 1,
            Day : 1,
            ResolutionCode : 1
          }
        }  
      ];
      var cursor = collection.aggregate(agg)
      cursor.forEach(doc => {
        console.log(doc)
      })
    
      
     await cursor.toArray((error, result) => {
        if(error) {
            return res.status(500).send(error);
        }
        cursor.forEach(doc => {
            res.send(doc)
          })

    });

  })// connection ends here
})
module.exports = router;
```

-> above code gives returns a json and then the server crushes

I can see the restults of
"  *cursor.forEach(doc => {
console.log(doc)})*  "
in the terminal and this seems to be working ok.What i am asking is how to return a response in json.Something like " *res.json(cursor)* "   I tried some different functions/methods to do this but none seems to work.

**Update**
After an answer i tried this

```js
cursor.toArray((error, result) => {
        if(error) {
            return res.status(500).send(error);
        }
        cursor.forEach(doc => {
            res.send(doc)
          })
    
    });
```

The above code when tested with Postman returns 1 json document from the database.The problem is that it returns only one and then the server crashes.The documents i want to return are multiple. The error message is *Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client*

Comment: That's because you're not waiting until your process is done, you might have already returned API response by the time your process is done & again you're trying to send it..

Comment: @srinivasy  i tried by using async and await but nothing changed,same results (1 doc in response) and same error

Comment: Can you give me the complete aggregation, what do you've in it !!

Comment: @srinivasy
i just edited the original question

Comment: Query is ok, Did you try to run the same query in mongoShell or any client like robo3T with same input values & see what's being returned ?

Comment: `cursor.forEach` and `cursor.toArray()` are incompatible. ForEach retrieves all docs and if you call `.toArray()` after, cursor is "empty"

Comment: you need to remove `var cursor = collection.aggregate(agg)
      cursor.forEach(doc => {
        console.log(doc)
      })`

Comment: @Valijon
I still don't know what's going on :( I am still trying stuff written on the answers

Comment: Check my answer again please

Comment: @Valijon
Thanks a lot,i owe you big time

Comment: You are welcome bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call [.toArray()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.toArray/) method to return all results.

**EDIT:** Debugged the code. Changed `Route` to `App`

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var router = express.Router();
var assert = require('assert')
const URL = 'mongodb+srv://user:user@cluster0-0pwss.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
//const CircularJSON = require('circular-json');
//const {parse, stringify} = require('flatted/cjs');

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.get('/:AreaName/:Resolution/:Year/:Month/:Day', (req, res) => {
  const _AreaName=req.params.AreaName
  const _Resolution=req.params.Resolution
  const _Year = parseInt(req.params.Year)
  const _Month = parseInt(req.params.Month)
  const _Day = parseInt(req.params.Day)

  MongoClient.connect(URL,{
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true}, 
    async (err, client) => {
      if (err) throw err; 
      else console.log('connected to db');
      assert.equal(null, err) 
      const db = client.db('energy')
      var collection = db.collection('ActualTotalLoad')
      const agg = [
        { 
          $match : 
          {
            AreaName: _AreaName,
            Day : _Day,
            Month: _Month,
            Year: _Year
          }
      },

        {
          $lookup:
          {
            from: 'ResolutionCode',
            localField: 'ResolutionCodeId',
            foreignField : 'Id',
            as: "resolution_codes"
          }
        },
        {
          $unwind: {path : "$resolution_codes"}
        },

        { 
          $match : {'resolution_codes.ResolutionCodeText' : _Resolution}
        },
        {
          $addFields : {ResolutionCode : '$resolution_codes.ResolutionCodeText',
                        Source :'entso-e',
                        Dataset :'ActualTotalLoad'
        }
        },

        {
          $project : 
          {
            _id:0,
            Id : 1,
            ResolutionCodeId:1,
            Source : 1,
            AreaName: 1,
            Year : 1,
            Month : 1,
            Day : 1,
            ResolutionCode : 1
          }
        }  
      ];
      var cursor = collection.aggregate(agg)

      await cursor.toArray((error, result) => {
        if(error) {
            return res.status(500).send(error);
        }
        res.send(result);
    });

  })// connection ends here
})
module.exports = router;

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

---

**Result:**
[image: Result]

Comment: doesn't work,it says await is only used in asychronous functions.The i removed await and it is doing the same this as before:   returns the data in terminal and never  responds anything when i use postman

Comment: Updated. Check again

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time. Now it returns an empty array.Maybe i should upload my fulll code? (to check the aggregate function)

Comment: Run your aggregation in terminal to check if it returns something

Comment: the cursor.forEach(doc => {
            console.log(doc)
          })   returns exacly what i want , but i will check it in terminal in 5 minutes thank you

Comment: i used the second suggestion and i got : TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
        .Maybe i shoudl convert somehow to string first?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this :

```
/* Frameworks Used + constants */
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var assert = require('assert')
const URL = 'an Atlas MongoDB'
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient


router.get('/base/:param1/:param2/:param3', (req, res, next) => {

    MongoClient.connect(URL, (err, client) => {
        assert.equal(null, err)
        const db = client.db('DB')
        db.collection('Collection').aggregate([{
            /* ... an aggregate with:  $lookup,$unwind,$match,$addFields,$project ..... */
        }]).toArray((err, resp) => {
            if (err) res.send({ error: err.message }); // (Or) res.status(400).end();
            if (resp.length) res.json(resp)
            res.send({ data: 'No docs found' })
        });
    })
})


module.exports = router;
```

(Or)

```
/* Frameworks Used + constants */
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var assert = require('assert')
const URL = 'an Atlas MongoDB'
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient


router.get('/base/:param1/:param2/:param3', (req, res, next) => {

    MongoClient.connect(URL, async (err, client) => {
        if(err) res.send({ error: 'DB connectivity error' });
        try {
            assert.equal(null, err)
            const db = client.db('DB')
            let resp = await db.collection('Collection').aggregate([{
                /* ... an aggregate with:  $lookup,$unwind,$match,$addFields,$project ..... */
            }]).toArray();
            if (resp.length) res.json(resp)
            res.send({ data: 'No docs found' })
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error ::', error)
            //res.status(400).end(); (Or)
            res.send({ error: error.message });
        }
    })
})


module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. It returns {} (empty json) :(

Comment: @Ermolai : Did you check you're connection to correct DB & collection ?

Comment: using the console.log  i get the correct results so i think that i am connecting to the DB+collection.But if u are willing to help i can give u the link to atlas db so u can check by yourself,my db is used only for learning pursoses

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar issue before and what it was doing was returning the promise itself. If it's an array of promises, you might want to try something like this:

`Promise.all(resp).then(values => res.json(values))`